# Trying to Write Unit Test with MSTest for DataType.PhoneNumber in C#

Tags: c#, mstest, phone-number

I am new to MSTest.  I have a data type PhoneNumber:

```
public class PhoneNumber : ValueObject
{
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I need to write a unit test for it.  A couple of questions:

1. Is there any built in capabilities for MS Test to validate data
   types?
2. Is there sample code on how to validate a phone number?

Comment: The official documentation is always a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`[Phone]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.phoneattribute) attribute instead.

[PhoneAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs#L7) is derived from `DataTypeAttribute` and overrides the `IsValid` method which is what checks that the value is in fact a valid phone number.

Using

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
```

does not do anything for phone number validation and is being used incorrectly in the shown example above

`DataTypeAttribute` is primarily used as a base attribute to create custom and targeted validation attributes.

For demonstration purposes, say I have the following class to be tested

```
public class PhoneNumber : ValueObject {
    public PhoneNumber(string number) {
        Number = phoneNumber;
    }

    [Phone]
    public string Number { get; private set; }

    //...
}
```

Review the following MSTest tests for both valid and invalid phone numbers

```
[TestClass]
public class PhoneNumberTests {
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow("555-5555")]
    [DataRow("555-555-5555")]
    [DataRow("1-555-555-5555")]
    public void Should_Be_Valid(string number) {
        //Arrange
        var subject = new PhoneNumber(number);
        var context = new ValidationContext(subject, null, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        //Act
        var actual = Validator.TryValidateObject(subject, context, results, true);

        //Assert
        actual.Should().BeTrue();
        results.Should().BeEmpty();
    }

    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow("abcd")]
    [DataRow("5555a")]
    [DataRow("abc5555a")]
    public void Should_Not_Be_Valid(string number) {
        //Arrange
        var subject = new PhoneNumber(number);
        var context = new ValidationContext(subject, null, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        //Act
        var actual = Validator.TryValidateObject(subject, context, results, true);

        //Assert
        actual.Should().BeFalse();
        results.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }
}
```

Note the use of the static [`Validator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator) class used to evaluate the adorned properties and validate that the object is valid.

Comment: What is a ValidationContext?

Comment: @MikeLenart Reference [ValidationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext?view=netframework-4.8). The Validator needs that when doing validations.